# Java generics multiple arguments with constraints

Tags: java, generics

I was able to find how to declare generics with single argument and multiple constrains and generics with multiple arguments, but strangely enough, not a generic with multiple argument *and* constraints:

```
public class Page<U, T implements IPaginableBy<U>> extends ArrayList<T> { }
```

gives me syntax error after `T`: "java: > expected". Is it not possible to constrain a an argument on generic type more than one argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public class Page<U, T implements IPaginableBy<U>> extends ArrayList<T> { }
```

to

```
public class Page<U, T extends IPaginableBy<U>> extends ArrayList<T> { }
```

Constrained type arguments always use the `extends` keyword.

Comment: Accepting this answer when it allows me (10 mins). Sorry, this was a dumb syntax error - this (redundant?) differentiation between `extends` and `implements` is a bit confusing.